# Why only 2 tangents can be drawn to a hyperbola?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Today we were introduced to what's an hyperbola its properties and hence equation of tangents, normal, pole, polar.

I was stunned when my professor said that we can draw only two tangents to a hyperbola (whether same branch or different). So my confusion begins here.

Now equation of tangent in parametric form is $\frac{x\sec(\theta)}{a}-\frac{y\tan(\theta)}{b}=1$ . Reducing it with double angle formulae, I got quadratic in $\tan(\theta/2)$  which means two tangents can be drawn. But if you just see a hyperbola without much details, a beginner like me would glance and say $4$ tangents can be drawn (with common logic).

> What condition is it that justifies that, at maximum, only two tangents can be drawn except the way on which we proved in class. I am probably looking for a geometric clarification.

Thanks

Comment: Actually, if your point is “inside” the hyperbola, there is no tangent drawable to it. But does it surprise you that there are only two tangents to a circle from a point outside it? If not, you might be interested to know that circle and hyperbola are (projectively) equivalent in a way that preserves tangency and the possibility of drawing tangents.

Comment: From outside the hyperbola I know it seems like four tangents can be drawn but if you extend the tangents on both sides you will find 2 out of the 4 tangents you imagined actually overlap.

Comment: Ya like the x formed has two tangents same

Comment: @Lubin can you justify that there can be drawn no tangent from centre of hyperbola to hyperbola

Comment: Projectively @Anusha, there *are* tangents to the hyperbola from the center: they’re the asymptotes. Notice that if $P$ is one one of the asymptotes but not the other, there’s only one tangent in the finite plane. The other tangent is the asymptote that $P$ lies on.

Comment: @Lubin yup thank you

Answer (score 5):

If I well understand you want to prove that we can have at most two tangent lines to a conic passing through a common point.
This is a simple consequence of the fact that the equation of a conic is second degree.

Let $f^{(2)}(x,y)=0$ be the equation of the conic and $P=(x_P,y_p)$ a point. The stright lines between $P$ are represented by the equation $y-y_P=m(x-x_P)$ and the common points of any such lines with the conic are the solutions of the system:
$$
\begin{cases}
f^{(2)}(x,y)=0\\
y-y_P=m(x-x_P)
\end{cases}
$$

Substituting $y$ from the equation of the lines in the first equation we find an  equation $R^{(2)}(x,m)=0$ that is of second degree in $x$ and contains the parameter $m$.  The line is tangent to the conic iff this equation has only one real solution, i.e. if the discriminant $\Delta_R^{(2)}(m)=0$.

Since the discriminant is a quadratic function of the coefficients, this is a second degree equation in $m$ and we have three possibilities:

1)the equation:  $\Delta_R^{(2)}(m)=0$ has no real solutions. This menas that we have no tangent lines form $P$. We say that $P$ is an ''internal'' point of the conic.

2) The equation has one (double) real solution: there is only one tangent line and the point $P$ is a point of the conic.

3) We have two distinct real solutions of the equation, so we have two tangent lines and the point $P$ is ''external''.

Answer (score 3):

If we take the hyperbola $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1,$$ suppose that $y=mx+c$ is a tangent.

Solving simultaneously, eliminating $y$, leads to the quadtatic equation in $x$:

$$(b^2-a^2m^2)x^2-2a^2cmx-(a^2c^2+a^2b^2)=0$$

Setting the discriminant equal to zero and simplifying leads to the condition:$$c^2+b^2=a^2m^2$$

Therefore for a given $(x,y)$ through which the tangent must pass, we are left with a simultaneous pair of equations, quadratic in $m$ and $c$, which will lead to at most two solutions, and therefore at most two tangents.