# Tangent to hyperbola without using derivative

Tags: calculus, euclidean-geometry, tangent-line

I'm asked to calculate the tangent to a hyperbola $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ at a point $P(x_1,y_1)$ without using derivatives (or limits), and we cannot use geometric transformations, because they 're not linear when applied to non-bounded curves (this is also something I would like an explanation to).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

You can use the equation of the lines thorough $P$ and take the system with the equation of the hyperbola. 
$$
\begin{cases}y-y_1=m(x-x_1)\\
\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1
\end{cases}
$$

the value of $m$ such that this system has only one solution it the slope of the tangent. (do you see why?)

If $P$ is a point of the hyperbola you find one only value of $m$.

Do you know how to find this value of $m$?

Comment: Yes, this seems correct! I will try and solve it now and get back to you.

Comment: You can also my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888090/why-only-2-tangents-can-be-drawn-to-a-hyperbola/1888131#1888131  or here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1921627/line-intersects-conic-at-exactly-one-point-implies-the-line-is-tangent-to-conic/1921649#1921649

Comment: $Δ=0$ for one solution, but this is still very perplex..I don't know if there is a faster way around this..

Comment: The faster way is using derivative.

Comment: We get to a point where we have an equation with constants and $m^2$. Why do we have two m's?

Comment: I’d suggest using a different form of equation of a line so that you don’t run into trouble at the vertices, where the tangent is vertical.

Comment: @amd What kind of equation do you mean?

Comment: $\alpha (x-x_1)+\beta (y-y_1)=0$ works for *any* line, but $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$ doesn’t handle vertical lines, which you’ll have at $x=\pm a$.

Answer (score 0):

Use an optical property of the hyperbola: a ray thrown from on focus to $(x1, y1)$ reflects as a continuation of the ray thrown from another focus. The bisector of the angle between the rays is normal to hyperbola.

The foci of your hyperbola are $(0, \pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2})$.

Comment: Yes, I thought of this too, but I'm supposed to solve it without using this as well